# What does the @ sign mean in an environment variabie?

Tags: windows, registry, environment-variables

I am seeing the below in a registry entry:

@%ProgramFiles%\path.....

I am just wondering what the @ symbol in this means/does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The components of the Windows operating system use the registry in a language-neutral manner. The data for a language-neutral registry value has the format

```
"@<PE-path>,-<stringID>[;<comment>]"
```

Read more: [Using Registry String Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374120(v=vs.85).aspx)